# Eloquent where clause not working as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm currently working on a private messaging system in Laravel.

I am trying to display a list of message threads in a user's inbox. This works similar to how an instant messaging system displays messages whereby all messages between 2 users are stored in a single thread.

The issue I am having is that I have multiple message types: "Message" and "Task". In the "Message" inbox, I only want to display message threads with the thread type as "Message". To do this I am using the following code in my controller:

```
    $messageThreads = Thread::where('type', 'Message')
    ->where('sender_id', $user)
    ->orWhere('recipient_id', $user)
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc('updated_at');
```

This however isn't working and is still retrieving message threads where the type is "Task" instead of being limited to "Message"

I have also tried:

```
     $messageThreads = Thread::where('sender_id', $user)
    ->orWhere('recipient_id', $user)
    ->where('type', 'Message')
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc('updated_at');
```

But this also returned the same result.

The interesting thing is if I just leave it as

```
$messageThreads = Thread::where('type', 'Message')
```

It will only retrieve messages with the type "Message". It is only when I add the other "where" clauses, that it stops working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned you likely need to group your where clauses:

```
Thread::where('type','Message')
->where(function($query)
{
    $query->where('sender_id',$user)
    ->orWhere('recipient_id',$user);
})->get();
```

The reason is that you are looking for a `Thread`  `where` its `type` is `Message` `orWhere` its `recipient_id` is the  `$user`. Their may be messages which *aren't* of type message, but do have the user as a recipient ID.

#### Here it is in the laravel documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping

Comment: Many thanks, had to remove the quotation from $user but it is working as expected.

Comment: In fact I think return isn't necessary wanted to re-edit it X(